# Convert BITMAP to PNG using IImage interface on Windows Mobile

Tags: winapi, image, windows-mobile, native

I've got a handle to a BITMAP structure (HBITMAP) in a Windows Mobile application -- I'd like to save the bitmap as a PNG file, using the [IImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa915136.aspx) interface if possible. (There's no BMP file in this situation, the BITMAP is only in memory).

It looks like I could use IImagingFactory's [IImagingFactory::CreateImageEncoderToFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa919941.aspx) method to save the file but I think I'd first have to get the BITMAP converted into "IImage" format.

Any ideas on how to do this with native code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [CreateImageFromStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa919079.aspx) to read in your BITMAP data, that gives you an IImage.

Edit:

I did a little more research on this.  There are a couple paths, but I think the easiest is to:

1. create a [DIBSECTION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183567(VS.85).aspx) and blit your bitmap to it.
2. Create a [BitmapData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms925969.aspx) instance pointing to the DIBSECTION for the image data.
3. Call [CreateBitmapFromBuffer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa452203.aspx) to generate an [IBitmapImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms908972.aspx) interface
4. Push the IBitmapImage (which is an IImage) through your encoder.

Comment: "Stream" in this case is a pointer to an IStream interface that provides the source data stream for the image -- how do you go from BITMAP data to that?

Comment: There's no need to create a DIBSECTION you can call GetObject on a hBitmap to get a pointer to bitmap bits. You can check in this thread for more detailed info http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssmartdevicesnative/thread/1d0f32d4-256b-4b03-91d6-1c487b638c63